# Rechart line chart positioning itself on top of my drawer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, recharts

I'm creating a dashboard using tailwindcss and next.js + Recharts. I've followed the recharts documentation for creating my line chart.

The chart by itself is working right, and the drawer is also working right. The drawer has a z-index of 99 to ensure it is placed on top of all the elements but the chart is still showing on top

Chart component

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BarChart,
  Bar,
  Cell,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ResponsiveContainer,
} from "recharts";
const WeeklyIncome = ({
  data,
}: {
  data: {
    name: string;
    income: number;
    tax: number;
  }[];
}) => {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer
      className={"relative z-0 z0"}
      style={{
        position: "relative",
        zIndex: -1,
      }}
    >
      <BarChart
        width={500}
        height={300}
        data={data}
        margin={{
          top: 5,
          right: 30,
          left: 20,
          bottom: 5,
        }}
        barSize={20}
        className="z-0"
      >
        <XAxis dataKey="name" scale="point" padding={{ left: 10, right: 10 }} />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Bar dataKey="income" stackId={"a"} fill="#82ca9d" className="z-0" />
        <Bar dataKey="tax" stackId={"a"} fill="red" className="z-0" />
      </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};

export default WeeklyIncome;
```

Drawer Component

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import useClickOutside from "@/hooks/useClickOutside";

import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
const Drawer = ({
  isOpen,
  onClose,
  children,
}: {
  isOpen: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  const ref = useClickOutside(React.useRef(null), onClose);
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      {isOpen && (
        <motion.div
          className={`fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50 z-[99]`}
          animate={{
            opacity: 1,
          }}
          initial={{
            opacity: 0,
          }}
          exit={{
            opacity: 0,
          }}
        >
          <motion.div
            className={`fixed left-0 top-0 w-80 h-full bg-white z-[99]`}
            animate={{
              x: 0,
            }}
            initial={{
              x: -300,
            }}
            exit={{
              x: -300,
            }}
            transition={{
              duration: 0.3,
              ease: "easeInOut",
            }}
            ref={ref}
          >
            <div className="flex justify-between items-center px-5 py-3">
              <h2 className="font-bold">EmprenAPP</h2>

              <button className="text-2xl" onClick={onClose}>
                &times;
              </button>
            </div>
            {children}
          </motion.div>
        </motion.div>
      )}
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default Drawer;
```

As you see i've tried adding z-index to all the elements of the chart but none seems to be working [This is what i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICMee.png)

And i'm expecting it to show beneath the drawer as you could imagine

Comment: Do you mind sharing the drawer component code? I've created a sandbox and implemented recharts + MUI drawer and it works fine.

Comment: @CynthiaE. I've edited the question to add my drawer. I'm trying to make most of it by hand so there might be a few things that are weird, sorry for that. Thanks for your time!